# ESET Remote Administrator Console showing infected files on a client, but threat log is empty

Tags: networking, security, anti-virus

We recently deployed ESET NOD32 Antivirus on our small domain network and use the Remote Adminstrator to manage everything remotely.

On a recent full system scan, one of the clients shows **10 infected files** of which **4 have been cleaned** in the scan log. The strange thing, however, is that the threat log is empty.

- Is there any reason why the threat log is empty?
- What has happened to the 6 remaining uncleaned files?
- Where can I view information on what files are infected and what they have been infected with? I know this can be done through the scan log properties screen, but with 958790 files scanned, I obviously do not want to browse through this list.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer (sorry!) but have you tried the [Official ESET Support Forum](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/forumdisplay.php?f=15)? The community there is very active.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; I have asked the same question there now but so far I have not gotten an answer yet. Usually SF is faster than any support forum :)